# Copying Questions From Definition Stage

Tags: discussion

I've never been involved in the start up of a stack exchange site before, but it seems to me like we should be copying some questions from the definition stage which were voted on as good questions. Is this something that is normally done? Is there a reason not to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me. As long as we only port the good questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I thought of the same thing myself, but then I decided we should only do this as long as we're interested in the answers, and not only for the sake of creating content.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Fair enough. I think that makes sense :-)

Comment: Correct. Questions should only be asked if it is an actual problem you have. Area 51's [example questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924?tab=ontopic&phase=definition#tab-top) are *really* only intended to help *define* the site scope. They don't necessarily translate into great questions.